# Remover proyecto del IDE STS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Como puedo remover los proyectos que tengo en el IDE STS para empezar a trabajar un nuevo pero que no vaya a perder el proyecto.

Cada vez que creo un nuevo proyecto debo crear un nuevo WorkSpace?

Cuál es la forma adecuada de nombrar los WorkSpace?.

Deseo remover el proyecto backendninja y empezar un nuevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según tengo entendido está basado en Eclipse. Hay otra pestaña que  se llama project explorer. Ahí es donde manejas los proyectos. Estás en la vista de pakcages.

Comment: @Angel, igual habilité el explorador de proyectos pero no veo como cerrarlo del todo.

Comment: No necesitas cambiar de espacio de trabajo. En la pestaña de project explorer, sobre la carpeta de tu proyecto haz `click derecho>close project`. Si lo que quieres es que no aparezca entonces haces `click derecho>delete`. Para crear un nuevo proyecto en cualquier parte de esta ventana haces `click derecho>new>project`

Comment: @Angel, click derecho>delete no me elimina el proyecto fisicamente?, cual es el efecto sobre el proyecto?.

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba y observo que elimina físicamente los proyectos.

Comment: Hay una opción para que no elimine los ficheros del disco. Antes de eliminar te la presenta.

Comment: @Angel, no me la presentó, simplemente elimino el proyecto completo.